# How can I embed a scrollable text box to output text on my web page?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to embed a scrollable text box to output text on my web page, in HTML or JavaScript?

I am trying not to use any Java libraries if possible.

Comment: By "scrolling" do you mean "automatically scrolling"?

Comment: Or do you mean scrollable?  By "text box" do you mean <textarea> or a "custom" element?

Comment: yes, <textarea> will work. Thanks, didn't know about it.

Comment: Good someone could help you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Answer stolen.  >_<  +1 anyway.  (No worries.)  ;P

Comment: @Strager: Sorry! If it's any consolation I always upvote an excellent strager answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

    #messages{
        border : solid 2px #ff0000; background : #D5D5D5;  padding : 4px; width : 500px; height : 350px; overflow : auto; 
    }
</style>

    <div id='messages'>
</div>
```

to scroll down with jquery:

```
$('#messages').scrollTop( $('#messages')[0].scrollHeight );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is pretty vague i am going to recommend [jScroller](http://jscroller.markusbordihn.de/) (since i've used it for some projects)